# Ember.js Stand-Alone Browser App

Tags: web-applications, ember.js, ember-cli, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm using Ember CLI for my project and was wondering if there was a way to build my project then open it in my browser by clicking on the index file.

My end goal is to wrap it and serve it as a desktop/ios/android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ember build --environment production

this will create a build in the 'dist' directory. Included is a generated index.html

run a server when in that directory (I use python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4200)

then, when you go to localhost:4200 you'll be accessing your production build's index.html
which will also server the other precompiled assets in that directory

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I can't have a server running for the app. It's literally a wrapper around the index file. Ember Tools does this. It builds your project and gives you a compiled static index file that you can open and run locally without a server.

Ember Tools hasn't been updated for the past year and I was hoping to stick with Ember CLI